# Opening a command window and passing content to it using Python

Tags: python, windows

I am currently working with a software package that allows you to create Python scripts and execute them from inside that package. The results of any script are saved back into the program. When the script executes, it does not show a command prompt window.

Is there an easy way to open a command prompt window from inside the script and pass over information for display, such as a dataframe header, a string or a list of values?

I have found from earlier SO posts that I can use:

```py
import os
os.system('cmd /k "Some random text"')
```

This works as expected, but when I use the following code:

```py
x = str(2 * 2)
output= f'cmd /k "{x}"'

os.system(output)
```

The number 4 is passed to the command window, but the following message appears:

`'4' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: You are passing a command to execute... `4` is - as the error message said - not a command. Maybe you meant `echo 4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the question.

```
'4' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Open cmd and type anything it will give error unless we type something which is recognized by cmd. e.g a help command.

if there is something we want to type in cmd and let it get processed/printed on console we use a command

> echo

[image]

in your program only the echo command was missing, which will let your output get printed on cmd.

[image]

> Last but not the least, always remember the ZEN of Python

[image]

Comment: Thanks Pran Sukh. I thought it may have been something that simple :) . As mentioned in the comment to the other answer, when I attempt to print a list that is 2,200 items long nothing shows up. Also, when I print a dataframe header it shows the first few columns, followed by .... and then the last few columns. Is this a limitation of this method?

Finally, how can I echo multiple lines in the same command window using this method?

Comment: if the requirement is to read content from file and print on cmd then use command **type fileName.txt**

**os.system('cmd /k type fileName.txt')**

i used a file with which have 6000 lines (it was a huge log file).

Comment: There is no limitation with this method, from you comment i can guess you are trying to print the whole dataframe by default python will show first few and last few dataFram values, use proper method that how many lines you want to see from dataFrame.

Comment: The content is coming from the software package I am using. I can create a dataframe and work with it as normal in the Python script, but I am limited to how I can display information within the package. So I would like to output my results and other print statements to the command prompt. The output in the command line for the dataframe only shows the partial header, but no rows - not even the first 3 / last 3.

Comment: This may help: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-print-an-entire-pandas-dataframe-in-python/

Comment: Saving the dataframe to a text file using `.to_string()`, and then loading that text file works. Just need to disable line wrapping

Answer (score 1):

##### Use subprocess instead

The `subprocess` has some more benefits compared to `Os`:

> 1. The `subprocess` module provides a consistent interface to creating and working with additional processes.
> 2. It offers a higher-level interface than some of the other available modules, and is intended to replace functions such as `os.system()`, `os.spawn*()`, `os.popen*()`, `popen2.*()` and `commands.*()`.
>    [Reference](https://pymotw.com/2/subprocess/#:%7E:text=The%20subprocess%20module%20provides%20a%20consistent%20interface%20to,os.spawn%2A%20%28%29%2C%20os.popen%2A%20%28%29%2C%20popen2.%2A%20%28%29%20and%20commands.%2A)

If you want to write something like to print `4` in another `cmd` tab, do like this:

```py
import subprocess
var = '4'
subprocess.Popen(['start','cmd','/k','echo',var], shell = True, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, text = True)
```

**Result:**
[image]

- It opens another `cmd` tab and passes a command such as `echo var`.

Comment: "input" is a python keyword. Do not use that as a variable name.

Comment: Thanks! That works and allows me to print simple text to the command window. Is there a limit to the length of the string? For example, I am trying to print a list that has 2200 items, and nothing shows. Although in the prompt in the software shows the following error : `[WinError 206] The filename or extension is too long`

Comment: Anytime @rockdoctor ! No, there is no limitations, you can make your command as a `string` (with any lenght)  and pass it to the `subprocess`, and it will work ,as long as, the command is correct.

Comment: Hi @rockdoctor , have you seen my answer? I actually think it will help you.. please take a look at it if you didn't already, and give me some feedbacks. If it was helpful, I'll be so delighted  to give my answer an upvote . Cheers.